# Unable to setup kuberenetes with VM binded with Public IP

Tags: kubernetes

I took a Ubuntu VM from some cloud service with the public IP and trying to do 
`kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=<public ip>`
but it always fail with error as follows:-

```
Unfortunately, an error has occurred: timed out waiting for the condition
```

This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

But it is working, if I try it by VM's private IP.
Do someone have any idea why it is happening.
Or any idea to setup cluster using public ip.

Comment: What's in kubelet logs?

Answer (score 0):

`kube-apiserver` is configured with `hostNetwork: true` which means it uses node network system.

Cloud VM PublicIP usually isn't configured on the VM's interface, so you can't use it for `apiserver-advertise-address=`. `kubelet` just can't bind `kube-apiserver` process to nonexistent local interface. It works well only if you specify IP address, configured on master's node VM interface and which is accessible from worker nodes.